# extending the user model to create a user2 model

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-authentication, django-allauth

I have a requirement of two types of login in my django project where one login is for students and one login is for teachers.

I have gone through the Django documentation and other internet resources, and I have come up with a simple design solution but I am not sure about the pros and cons as I am still quiet new to Django.

Solution I thought to solve this Problem:

1) For student login, I have succesfully integrated django-allauth and it is working fine.

2) Now for the teacher login, I am thinking to build a model as follows:

```
class Teacher(models.Model):
    teacher = models.OneToOneField(User,unique=True)
    identifier = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    #other fields
```

3) Then two forms over this model - Signup and Login for teachers and email verification form: Here I thought that I will create teacher object and student object on successful signup but I will set `is_active=False` and ask for email verification.On successful verification, I will set `is_active=True` so that a teacher can successfully login.

4) Avoid students from logging in the teachers section and teachers can login in the students section: Here I though of an identifier field to avoid authenticated students to login in the teachers section.

Please can anyone help me by providing your opinion on this solution or by suggesting some better alternative as I am still reading up more and more Django Documentation on this.

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 1):

You could create a single model 'user' and define there permissions by adding them to a group.

And have your Django application for teachers check if there in the group teacher.
You could create separate forms or check based on email (name.student@ or name@ ) and
before saving the model adding the group.

Keeping is_active on False is alway a good idea if you want to verify that a 'user' has given a correct email.

Answer (score 0):

I did an application which needed different permissions levels for Students, Teachers and a few different other User categories. I'm not sure if it's the best way to do it, but I did it by creating one UserProfile, as Eagllus mentioned, which had several categories for what kind of user profile it was. Something like:

```
PROFILE_CHOICES = (
    ('TE', 'Teacher'),
    ('ST', 'Student'),
)

class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    profile_type = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=PROFILE_CHOICES)
    '''other attributes'''
```

You can then decorate your views so only users of a certain type can access them.
Its not clear to me what you are trying to do in #3. It sounds like you want the user to be added as a teacher and student but only make them active by email verification?

I'm not familiar with django-auth but django-registration provides user registration where user account are activated via email. This may save you a significant amount of work.

Comment: Actually I am trying to verify the registration through email verification in #3. Actually my student login is live on web from past four months with around 1500 registrations so I dont want to make any change to the login mechanism of students. This idea of UserProfile seems good. I am investigating it further so that I can get it working in my scenario. Thanks!!